# How do I get rid of this space in my document

Tags: html, css

`enter code here`http://jsfiddle.net/rLP5V/
I have my document listed above, for some reason, even when I set margins to 0 the margin between the header1 and nav bar still shows and leaves an unnessecary blank between the both of them. Please let me know how to get rid of it. P.S. The page I am creating is for a project

Comment: Not that I'm preaching for a totally uniform web, but... Have you considered using Twitter Boostrap? Or an equivalent CSS framework?

Comment: @Bonatoc That wouldn't solve this issue.

Comment: Oh yes it would. But I see what you mean. SO is not place for advocacy or opinionated answers. Still, when I see these poor beginners sweat over stuff like this, and because I went there, I can only suggest a proper way for them to work, and to be all devices compliant. It's 2014 already.

Comment: This is not the place for this discussion. Bootstrap is bloated and unnecessary, beginner or not. Beginner's should be taught the correct way, IMHO.

Comment: Well, I answered, didn't I? But you are right, we are not here to debate. Especially when OP depends on Tumblr.

Comment: where you closed the h1 div ?

Answer (score 1):

Elements like `h1` and `ul` have usually their margin set by the browser's (user agent) own stylesheet unless explicitly overwritten :

```
h1 {
margin: 0;   
height: 50px; // SAME HEIGHT AS PROFILE PHOTO
}

ul {
 margin: 0;
}
```

See Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bonatoc/jhU85/1/

Look for the last lines added to the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The `h1` element has a margin defined by the browser. You will have to override this in your CSS.

Comment: Thank you, this worked, but it did affect my profilephoto by being a part of it, thank you -James

Comment: Updated Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/bonatoc/jhU85/3/